# How to make a frame pattern width rows, columns, and thickness input?

Tags: c++, for-loop, design-patterns

My lecturer gave me a homework to make a "*" pattern that looks like a picture frame. It kinda same  like the hollow square one but it's harder. It should work with any given input in length, width, and thick.

note:If statement is NOT ALLOWED.

Example input:
length:10
width:8
thick:2

output:

```
**********
**********
**      **
**      **
**      **
**      **
**********
**********
```

The plan is to split it into three parts
1st part

```
**********
**********
```

2nd part

```
**      **
**      **
**      **
**      **
```

3rd part (the same as the 1st part)

```
**********
**********
```

I know for this case the first part is to make two nested loop. But I got confused on making the second and the third part.

I've know how to make a square before which looks like this

```
for (int i = 1; i <= p; i++)
{
    for (int j = 1; j <= l ; j++)   
    {
        cout << "*";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

For the second part i knew there will be more loops included but i can't sem to find the solution.

the third part generally looks the same as the first one.

The output should looks like this

```
**********
**********
**      **
**      **
**      **
**      **
**********
**********
```

If anyone can explain how to do it it'll be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You can do this with `std::string` variables, using the [constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string), `std::string('*', length);`.  Another as `std::string('*', thickness)` and a third with `std::string(' ', length - 2*thickness);`.  Use a loop to print these strings in order.

Comment: It's just combining loops: "number of thickness" times "size", ("border width", "width minus border width twice", "border width") times height minus borderwidth twice, then repeat the top part.

Comment: In other words, use a "string" variable that contains the top frame bar.  Create a second "string" variable containing a middle row.  Print the appropriate string variables in loops.